# Dynamic Views Based on Variable

Tags: mysql

I'm using views to help slowly transition from a legacy database to a new one.  For example, there is a client table in the legacy database which I am re-implementing in the new database (both databases are on the same server).  I plan on replacing the client table with a client view in the legacy database that has the same signature as the original table.

I think my idea should work fine, except the new application is being developed in Rails, and depending on the environment the database name might be db_test, db_development or db_production.

How might I create a view in the legacy database that points to a table in the new database when the new database name will be changing?  I've tried a number of things, but it's a pretty strange problem so I'm not even really sure where to begin.

This is an example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
SET @db = 'db_development';
select * from @db.client;
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: When you say "depending on the environment", do you mean "depending on program state in Ruby"?  In which case, surely you can make the database selection there (e.g. upon connecting to MySQL)?

Comment: Well the new Rails app is only part of the equation.  The legacy database will have views that point to the new Rails database as the legacy application will have to function in conjunction with the Rails app for some time.  The database those views point to will have to change along with the Rails environment.

Comment: I've looked at using symbolic links, but that only works with MyIASM tables.  I looked at using MySQL Proxy, but it looks too complicated for this situation.  I looked at using variables, but that only works with prepared statements which don't work within views.  I think what I'm going to try is to create a separate gem that can process sql.erb files.  Then I can run something like `rake db:switch development` and have it recreate the views to point to a different db.

Comment: Just saw your last response... yeah I was concerned about the performance impact myself.  Triggers might work.  Or even if not triggers, maybe just another way to sync the data.  I'll look into it.

Comment: I had assumed that the structure of data in the legacy database was different to the new one, so triggers would enable you to perform any necessary translations, whereas proxying/symlinks/etc would not... but if they are the same structure, MySQL Proxy sounds like quite a good bet - or else, you could do something very simple with three daemons listening on different ports/at different sockets, and a little redirect that sends traffic to the right place?

Comment: I'm not sure if MySQL Proxy would even work, actually.  Because I might have joins between the two databases.  Honestly, your trigger idea might be ideal.  The legacy database is always the same name, so the triggers could be the same in each environment.  It would also mean fewer changes to the legacy application as I could, in theory, keep the existing database structure exactly the same.  Also, I will never allow the legacy app to make modifications to the new database, so the triggers will only need to function one way.

Comment: I did end up going with triggers.  It seems like it's going to work.  Thanks again.

Comment: No worries.  I'll post as an answer for you to accept.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define triggers on both databases to keep them in sync.